# KB Pressing While Mousebuton is Pressed

Tags: lua, scripting, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I want to create a script that presses 1 then 2 then 3 while LCTRL and RMB is pressed.

```
 EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
 function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if IsModifierPressed("lctrl") then
      repeat
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
        repeat
       PressKey("1")

    Sleep(105) 

    ReleaseKey("1")

    Sleep(70) 

    PressKey("2")

    Sleep(105) 

    ReleaseKey("2")

    Sleep(40) 

    PressKey("3")

    Sleep(40) 

    ReleaseKey("3")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED` event

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 then
      while IsModifierPressed("lctrl") do
        PressKey("1")
        Sleep(105) 
        ReleaseKey("1")
        Sleep(70) 
        PressKey("2")
        Sleep(105) 
        ReleaseKey("2")
        Sleep(40) 
        PressKey("3")
        Sleep(40) 
        ReleaseKey("3")
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i did try that one but its not doing anything. I just did one that is working but i cant manage to add repeat command in it. I want it to repeat as long as i keep LCTRL pressed


EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);

function OnEvent(event, arg)
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
       PressKey("1")

 Sleep(105) 

 ReleaseKey("1")

 Sleep(70) 

 PressKey("2")

 Sleep(105) 

 ReleaseKey("2")

 Sleep(40) 

 PressKey("3")

 Sleep(40) 

 ReleaseKey("3")
end
end

Comment: @SebiMiara - Answer updated, now the script works while LCtrl is pressed.